# How do I store in-memory variables with Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to assign avatar but I get an error when I try to use it.

I am coming from a Node background, where I can assign values and then modify them from requests. What should I look at to maintain state?

```
defmodule Chatroom.LobbyChannel do
  require Runner
  use Phoenix.Channel

  {:ok, pid: spawn(fn -> Runner.input() end)}

  avatar = %{x: 0, y: 0}

  def join("lobby", _payload, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("new_message", payload, socket) do
    case payload["message"] do
      "hello" -> broadcast! socket, "new_message", payload
      "jump" -> send pid, {:jump, self, [avatar: avatar, socket: socket]}
      _ -> nil
    end

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_reply do
    receive do
        {:result, mover, socket} -> broadcast! socket, "new_message", [name: "State", message: "5"]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an abstraction on top of `GenServer`, called [`Agent`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Agent.html). From the documentation:

> Agents are a simple abstraction around state.
>
> Often in Elixir there is a need to share or store state that must be accessed from different processes or by the same process at different points in time.
>
> The Agent module provides a basic server implementation that allows state to be retrieved and updated via a simple API.

`Agent` is not Phoenix-specific, it’s Elixir-wide. In Elixir guides there is a [great how-to on the subject](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html).

Comment: Thanks - where would I start my Agent? It looks like start_link is used to link a function prior to using it. Where would that go in a Phoenix stack?

Comment: It depends on the lifecircle of your agent. If you need it to be available always, start it within the main app as supervised worker.